# Unable to install ubuntu 16.04 lts on windows 10 64bit asus rog laptop

Tags: 16.04

Unable to install ubuntu from bootable usb.After selecting the second option in the grub for installing ubuntu,it redirects to ubuntu loading screen with 5 dots under ubuntu icon.It gets stuck here indefinitely. Also disabled fast boot option.

works fine on vm though.
Please help

Comment: Try using older versions of Ubuntu or try something
Like kubuntu. Do you have a UEFi system

Comment: Can you run the "Try Ubuntu" option successfully?

Comment: Yes,I did that already.Same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, do you fix the issue?

Comment: Nopes.Still have not.

Comment: I have the same laptop and same issue. Ubuntu 15.10 also doesn't work.

Comment: i think you should use nomodeset. search askubuntu you will find same problems!